# Elasticsearch query from JSON formatted string?

Tags: elasticsearch, cassandra, elassandra

I am working with Elasticsearch and I need to query value from the document which stored as JSON formatted string.

Is there any option to query form Elasticsearch which stored JSON formatted string?

**Please see my use case**

I am saving my application data in Cassandra and replicating these data to elastic search (I am using [elassandra](https://github.com/strapdata/elassandra) bundled version for it). But in Cassandra, I have a field with `list<text>` and it holds JSON array with nested JSON objects.

When I map the Cassandra table to Elasticsearch (as per suggested by elassandra doc) it mapping Cassandra field name as JSON key in Elasticsearch and entire JSON array considered as JSON formatted string.

Now I need to do the query based on the key inside the JSON which are stored as JSON string in Elasticsearch.

Please see the sample of my data stored in the Elasticsearch:

```
    {
    "status": {
        \"visibilityStatus\": true,
        \"deleteStatus\": true
    }
}
```

Here status is Cassandra field name and remaining is the value of one record.

Now I need to search the record with `deleteStatus=true`, any clue, please.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have query, which is already there in JSON format,you want to use that json in your code to query ES ?

Comment: Could you be more specific? And maybe provide a little bit of code?  Can't understand what is your request

Comment: I updated my question, please see my use case.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should store your status object as an Elasticsearch object backed by an UDT (a Cassandra User Defined Type), and then, you will be able to search in with an elasticsearch nested query.

You can create your cassandra schema with a UDT for the status column and auto-discover the mapping, or specify the elasticsearch mapping to generate the CQL schema. The optional cql_udt_name allows to name the UDT name, as shown bellow :

```
XContentBuilder mapping = XContentFactory.jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                    .startObject("properties")
                        .startObject("id").field("type", "keyword").field("cql_collection", "singleton").field("cql_primary_key_order", 0).field("cql_partition_key", true).endObject()
                        .startObject("event_timestamp")
                            .field("type", "date")
                            .field("format", "strict_date_hour_minute_second||epoch_millis")
                            .field("cql_collection", "singleton")
                        .endObject()
                        .startObject("event_info")
                            .field("type", "nested")
                            .field("cql_collection", "singleton")
                            .field("cql_udt_name", "event_info_udt")
                            .field("dynamic", "false")
                            .startObject("properties")
                               .startObject("event_timestamp")
                                .field("type", "date")
                                .field("format", "strict_date_hour_minute_second||epoch_millis")
                                .field("cql_collection", "singleton")
                            .endObject()
                        .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                    .endObject()
                .endObject();
```

Comment: Its worked for me, thank you :) Accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure about my solution is ok for you.

Can you try with  [JSON processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/json-processor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Ingest processor is not supported with elassandra, you should use the proposed mapping to index your UDT.
Thanks.